# Google Maps calculate visible part of the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Ok, i good a simple question about Google Maps.
Imagine there is a map the user scrolls half way out of screen on desktop. So only half of the map is visible on screen.
How can i calculate which part is visible, so i can put a marker in the center of the visible part of the map?

So if you check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/Honkoman/ghzgdLhw/

and scale the browser window like this:

[image]
You see that pressing "run" sets the marker not in the visible middle of the map.

That's because map.getCenter works with the canvas dimensions, not the visible part of the map. So how can this be done?

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "half the map is visible"?  Are you trying to not count the grey regions above +85/below -85 degrees degrees of latitude?

Comment: No i mean only the part visible on screen. without the offscreen part, when scrolled out of screen.

Comment: That is just `map.getBounds()` (assuming `map` is a `google.maps.Map` object).  How are you displaying the map?  What does that code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 map.getBounds()
```

> Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If more than one
>   copy of the world is visible, the bounds range in longitude from -180
>   to 180 degrees inclusive.

for obtain the coord of the visible maps

or directly you can use getCenter

```
map.getCenter();
```

and for marker

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
```

for the bound you can use  this tecnique

```
    aNord   =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();   
    aEst    =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    aSud    =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();   
    aOvest  =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
```

Comment: I want to get only the bounds of the part of the map that is visible on screen, without the part that if offscreen.

Comment: getBound return only the actual visible part . .

Comment: thats not working. i always getr the same bounds no matter how much of the map is visible or offscreen.

Comment: update you question and show your code  .. i also posted a brief sample for get the coords ..

Comment: there is no code as it is a simple google map. no custom js code. the only question is how to position a marker in the center of the visible part of the map. i can try doing a fiddle.

Comment: For the browser  the map is placed in all the div container  indipendently of the scroolling .. ..for what i  know google maps don't have function for getting the coord of this part of map .... google maps provide pan function for move the map .. and getBound retriive the coord of the corner of map in dov container ..

Comment: Yes that's the problem :)

Comment: Just for curiosity ....  why you use a scroolable maps ?.. (normally is used a pan  ..able  .. map)

Comment: I'm not using a scrollable map. Its just that i have a list on the left, which when hovering shows a marker in the map on the right. If the user scrolls the website down and hovers over the list, the marker gets placed out of view because more than half of the map are outside.

Comment: I've also had a similar problem and I solved it by placing the variable list box above the map in a fixed position and scroll doing only of its content and not all over the map ..

Comment: Thats not possible here because the map has a sticky behaviour and is fixed when scrolling most of the time.